# Why does list.append(obj) modify obj in Python?

Tags: python

I have a strange problem with `list.append()`. I build a list joining some values from a dict, as follows:

```
In [3]: myDict = {'k1': u'value1', 'k2': [u'value2']}

In [4]: myList = myDict['k2']

In [5]: myList
Out[5]: [u'value2']

In [6]: myList.append(myDict['k1'])

In [7]: myList
Out[7]: [u'value2', u'value1']

In [8]: myDict 
Out[8]: {'k1': u'value1', 'k2': [u'value2', u'value1']}
```

I don't understand the reason why `myDict` is modified after `append` in `In [6]` (see the difference between `In [2]` and `Out [8]`).

Comment: Because they refer to the same object.

Comment: Becuase myDict and myDict['k2'] _refer to the same list_.

Comment: `myList is myDict['k2']` - a better question might be *why did you expect something else to happen?*

Comment: Assignment statements in Python do not copy objects, they create bindings between a target and an object.

Comment: @Doon beautiful explanation should copy this for future use :)

Comment: @VigneshKalai Stolen from copy in the stdlib :)

Comment: You may find this article helpful: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Comment: this really boils down to "pass by reference" concept (not just in python but in many other languages)...see my answer in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33222944/append-vs-redefining-variable-in-python/33223855#33223855

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because when you assign `myDict['k2']` to `myList` you are actually just creating a pointer, `myList`, to the value with key `k2` in `myDict`. You need to create a copy of `myDict['k2']` otherwise you are just modifying the original.

Try `myList = list(myDict['k2'])`.

Answer (score 2):

`myDict[k2]` is a pointer to a list object.
You then set myList to point to the same list object.
when you modify the list, all of the pointers that point to it see the modified one.